# Can someone help me with "dbxUpsert" function from the "dbx" library in Postgres?

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, r-dbi

Here is my use case: I have a code in R which gives a df as the final output. The df has 4 columns. I want to pass this to a postgres table and whenever the code run and the df gets updated it should update the same on postgres where it should append new entries while modifying the ones which already exist. I have used [dbx library](https://github.com/ankane/dbx)

My code-

```r
dbxUpsert(db, table, required_info, where_cols=c("opportunity_id"))
```

`db` is the connection while `table` has the table name and `required_info` is the resultant dataframe.
`opportunity_id` is the primary key.

When I run the code twice it gives me an error:

```
Error: Failed to fetch row: ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time
HINT:  Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command have duplicate constrained values.
```

It should ignore the ones already present even if values are same.

Comment: From the error and hint, it appears that your frame as duplicates among `"opportunity_id"`. You can find the duplicated ids with `subset(required_info, duplicated(opportunity_id))`. This will give you the 2nd and subsequent rows for each repeated ids. From there, you need to figure out what you are intending to upsert.

Comment: Any progress, SurajitShasmal?

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this exactly solved the issue that i was facing.

Comment: @r2evans whenever i upsert the values, i want to change a column named synced in my db to false only for the rows that are updated, how do i do that

Comment: Is there a column named `synced` in `required_info`? If not, add it as all `FALSE` before upserting.